# how to get body content in joomla site

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to find all the images in a Joomla site page. I plan to use the following code:

`preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $pageBody, $imageArray);`

I believe that the above code would work if I was able to assign the `<body>` content of the page to the variable `$pageBody`. But I can't find the right method to do it.

I've found `JApplicationWeb` and `JApplicationSite`but I wasn't able to do it.

I'm using Joomla 3.7.4.

Comment: Can you say something why you want to get all the images? If you want to modify the images (eg. scale them), the best approach might be to write a content plugin and fix the images there, or write template overrides to override output. If you just need a list of all the images, this can be done in a system plugin in onBeforeRender. Please elaborate what you want to do with your images...

Comment: I want to get the images in the page to be able to add to the Open Graph tags (Facebook, Twitter, etc.).

Comment: @jonasfh, I want to get the images in the page to be able to add it to the Open Graph tags (Facebook, Twitter, etc.).

Comment: When you want to parse valid HTML, you should not be using regex (and your pattern is technically flawed / unreliable).  DomDocument will make for more readable, maintainable, and reliable code.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53346631/2943403 (my snippet will work regardess of the number and order of attributes in the img tag and you don't have to fuss with the accommodating different quoting symbols.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for `onAfterRender` event of system type plugin.

[Creating a Plugin for Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla)

You should create a plugin and add above event. This would be something similar to below approach.

```
class plgSystemCustomplugin extends JPlugin
{


        /**
         * 
         * @return boolean
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function onAfterRender()
        {
                $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
                $sHtml = $app->getBody();

                // Modify $sHtml

                // Set body back
                $app->setBody($sHtml);
        }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to do it without a plugin (I'm building a template). I guess that my previous mistake is that I was using  `$app->getBody()` without the `onAfterRender` event. Is this the only way to do it? What I really would like to do is be able to find the images in the current Joomla page and use it as an Open Graph tag (`og:image`).

Comment: I only know this way. Unless you have all document it's not possible to search for images.