# Joomla4 plugin getBody

Tags: plugins, joomla, system

In Joomla 3.x versions I use JResponse to get and set the body.

```
function onAfterRender() {
          $content = JResponse::getBody();
          ...
    }
```

But in Joomla4 it returns **Class 'JResponse' not found**.
So how to get the body in Joomla4?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get body content in joomla site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445667/how-to-get-body-content-in-joomla-site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [cross-posted answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/26304/12352)...

According to the [documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Application.WebApplication.html), `JApplicationWeb` seems to be alive and well in Joomla4.

> **since** 2.5.0
>
> **note** As of 4.0 this class will be abstract

- The getters:

  ```
  JApplicationWeb::getBody()
  ```

  Or

  ```
  JFactory::getApplication()->getBody()
  ```
- The setters:

  ```
  JApplicationWeb::setBody()
  ```

  Or

  ```
  JFactory::getApplication()->setBody()
  ```

---

Relevant references and examples:

- https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=941835
- https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/20879/12352
- https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/10232/12352
- https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/9953/12352
- https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23835/12352
- https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/9720/12352

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla4 use app

```
function onAfterRender() {
              $content = JFactory::getApplication()->getBody();
              JFactory::getApplication()->setBody($body);
              ...
        }
```